# How does the magician's hat enhance magic?

Tags: candy-box

[image: The magician's hat. Wearing this hat enhances your magic.]

**The magician's hat** is described as "*wearing this hat enhances your magic*". How does this work? How exactly does it "enhance my magic"?
<sub>[related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cq-NShfefks)</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The magician's hat** enables the purchase of **Earthquake scrolls**, which greatly damage everyone on the map, and **Imp invocation scrolls**, which will summon allied imps. In addition, **The magician's hat** will reduce the scroll cooldown from 20 seconds to 12 seconds.

**The magician's hat** will *not* increase the damage of your weapons, nor will it improve the effects of potions or scrolls.